# Hiding text: text-indent or color: transparent?

Tags: html, css

I see lot of times attempts to hide text with CSS, for instance:

```
<a class="back">back</a>    
a.back { text-indent: -9999px; display:block; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: url(/images/back.png); }
```

I always wonder why not to use:

```
a.back { color: transparent; display:block; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: url(/images/back.png); }
```

It seems to me semantically correct, and in addition, when I tried the text-indent approach, it caused a bug in iPad display: The text was displayed 99999px left to the anchor tag and caused a strange unnecessary horizontal scroll.
Is there a common known problem with the second code or it's OK to use?

Comment: whats wrong with display none?

Comment: display: none will hide the anchor itself, I want to hide the text only @Richlewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-size: 0px;` should do the trick.
If you want to make the button smaller than the text, you'll also need to add `line-height: 1em;` or something similar.

Comment: OK, seems like a nice solution, but still I ask: what's wrong with color: transparent?

Comment: Well, as Andy says, color: transparent means the text is still there, so it can be highlighted and dragged. It also means that you can never make the button smaller than the line-height of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Using the display property allows you to edit the state of an element in C#.

Here are 4 main display elements people use:

```
p.ex1 {display: none;}
p.ex2 {display: inline;}
p.ex3 {display: block;}
p.ex4 {display: inline-block;}
```

**display:none** means that the tag in question will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom). There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags. **visibility:hidden** means that unlike **display:none**, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page

But if you want to learn more about them you can go to this site: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

w3schools explains a lot of languages in a simple and understandable way.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @mufazmi thank you for telling me this. I edited my response to explain it more, like you said. thx

Answer (score -3):

Don't hide *content* and depend on a *background* image at all.

HTML provides a way to include images which have meaning (the `<img>` element) with text content for situations where the image can't be displayed (the `alt` attribute). There is no need to fake it with the stylesheet.

```
<a class="back"><img alt="back" src="/images/back.png"></a>
```

Icons are content and deserve to be treated as such. All efforts to use text and background images are ultimately hacks with limitations. The `<img>` element was designed for this use case.